# Import own *.py file from the python shell

Tags: python

I created a test file in Python 3 using vim named "test.py"

```
def addtwo(one, two):
    new = one + two
    return new
```

I saved that file in my `$HOME` directory.

then I open the Python shell by typing `python3`

In the shell I type:

```
from test.py import *
```

and I get this returned:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test.py'; 'test' is not a package
```

I figure that this is some sort of file path issue and did some Google searches, but I might not be formulating my question right.  Can someone shed some light please?

Comment: from test import *

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead of

```
from test.py import *
```

it's

```
from test import *
```

Comment: Thanks for helping a newbie!  LoL.  Worked.

Comment: @BenLilley it is usually not suggested to import `*` everything (unless in this case as it is Your own module and You probably know what You have in there (because sometimes by importing all there might be some name clashes and it may be harder to debug))

Comment: @Matiss Thanks, didn't know that.

Comment: @BenLilley This `import *` thing is mentioned in the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/): "Wildcard imports (`from <module> import *`) should be avoided, as they make it unclear which names are present in the namespace, confusing both readers and many automated tools."